# Is OpenSSH v5.9 still considered secure?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Some of our servers with Ubuntu 12.04 have a OpenSSH Version 5.9p1. I did not really find a version history of OpenSSH, but it seems this version was already living in 2011.

I also could not find if Ubuntu did some Security Patches on that version or if there were critical security problems. I found page [Security](http://www.openssh.com/security.html) of course, which seems uncritical for me, but is this really all the trouble since 2011?

Comment: You should get an eye on `ShellShock` on google ;) here you will find more infos about OpenSSH : http://www.cvedetails.com/product/585/Openbsd-Openssh.html?vendor_id=97

Comment: ShellShock? I thought I have asked about OpenSSH, did my keyboard just shuffle in some `bash`? Or did you just wanted some bashing the `bash`? ;-)

Comment: you can try `ssh serverip '() { :;}; echo Vulnerable'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 is a LTS release and will receive updates until April 2017.

As long as you're regularly patching (i.e. `apt-get upgrade`), you'll receive security fixes to packages in the default repositories. While you're still running 5.9, Ubuntu backports fixes.

You can see the Ubuntu 12.04 OpenSSH changelog here (the latest update is from August 2015):
http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh_5.9p1-5ubuntu1.7/changelog